# Alignment in TableLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to align two elements at left and right end of my `TableRow`(pic attached ). In the code shown below, when i write `android:layout_column="2"`, nothing happens. But when i add  `android:stretchColumns="1"` in `TableLayout`, it works and the elements get aligned as i want.
Though i understand the purpose of `strechColumns` and `layout_column`, i don't understand why this combination works and why not `android:layout_column`?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/about_speed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">         
    <TableRow>
       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/speed"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Current speed"/>

       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/speed_help"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/help_speed"
         android:layout_column="2"/>

    </TableRow>
```

[image]

Comment: may be use of TableLayout is your requirement but this is my suggestion you can achieve same layout in TextView only              <TextView
         android:id="@+id/speed"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/help_speed"
         android:text="Current speed"/>  and reduce your layout hierarchy

Comment: yes, this one also works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose which column to put your widget by using `android:layout_column` property, you define the Zero-based index of the column where you want your widget to be.

**Note**: if you specify an index greater than the actual cells count, the widget won’t appear.

In table layout each column occupies space equal to the size of the largest widget in it. But you can set the width of any column to take the largest available space, just like setting the width to 100 % in HTML. This is done by setting the property `android:stretchColumns` to the index of the column.
For more info see at [Android Table Layout](http://android-pro.blogspot.in/2010/02/table-layout.html)

**And in your case**
 you set `android:stretchColumns="1"`—The second column (because the column numbers are 0-based) is stretched to take up any available space in the row.
And `android:layout_column="2"` means your image will at columns position 2(note:Zero based index).

Therefore when you use `android:stretchColumns` with `android:layout_column`,it set image to column position 2 and you stretching column number 1  (**android:stretchColumns="1"**).

Finally in your design **text is at 0th position,Stretching 1st column(white space) and setting image at 2nd position**.

Comment: It is helpful but doesnt answers my question. Why the combination on stretchcolumns and column_layout works here but not only column_layout?

Comment: But in second column, i have "question-mark" image. It is not streching up.

Comment: @Diffy android:stretchColumns means,its takes all the available space.

Comment: Bu when i remove layout_column, the second image stretches.Only when the layout_column is 2 or high, it goes to the right

Comment: @Diffy when you use layout_column=2, yoru image will be at 2nd column position,and your table strech 1st column,which is whitespace,see edited answer.surely it may help you

Comment: yes, this makes sense now. But how this is determined that how much the white space will stretch? Why its pushing the 2nd image to the end?

Comment: @Diffy android:stretchColumns takes all the available whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

may be use of `TableLayout` is your requirement but this is my suggestion you can achieve same layout in `TextView` only

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/speed"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/help_speed"
  android:text="Current speed"/>
```

and reduce your layout hierarchy